# how to efficiently store user's information

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store details about users.Every user will have user name,e-mail,password,address,city,country,and few other fields.
What is best way to store it?
Should I store all this in one table?

Comment: Sunil - you might want to check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718901/how-to-efficiently-work-with-multiple-database-tables-in-ruby-on-rails/8720464#8720464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store related information in one table. If your users will be allowed to have one single address, for example, you may safely store the address components in a table with the user's base details (username, email, password).  Consider also the possibility of storing multiple addresses or emails per user.  In that case, you would have a separate table for addresses with a foreign key into the users table, on a userid field.

Example:

`users`:

```
userid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL
```

`user_addresses`, permitting multiple addresses per user...

```
addressid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
userid INT NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(2048) NULL,
streetno VARCHAR(2048) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userid)
```

Comment: Users will be allowed to have only single address.But which way is more efficient?

Comment: @sunil Querying against one table will be slightly more efficient if you don't plan to store multiple addresses, since you won't have to join.